# How to create and publish a Release using GitHub API v3 with curl?

Tags: curl, github, github-api

According to the github api documentation (https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/) I need to send a post request including a payload that requires the tag_name. So I proceeded to build the following curl request in order to try and publish an existing tag (0.0.5)

```
curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: token 1a1a1a11a11a11a11a11a11a11a1a11a1a1a1a1" https://api.github.com/repos/codeStyler87/test-tags/releases -d '{"tag_name":"0.0.5","target_commitish": "develop","name": "0.0.5","body": "Description of the release","draft": false,"prerelease": false}'
```

but i get HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found.

What's wrong with my request?

Am I using the API correctly?

Why GitHub API dont provide an accurate error message?

Comment: Works fine here. I forked your repo and issued your command with my fork and my access token and the release got created from the existing tag.

Comment: with the same curl command i use above?

Comment: can i see the branch you cloned from me? It looks to me that the release was created once I pushed the tag to the remote, however, it doesnt look like it is published.

Comment: Also I dont know how to explain that i get that 404. I have a valid token

Comment: I deleted my fork already. Yes, same command. What is the output if you run the command?

Comment: I'm getting: `{ "message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3" }` , which it does not make sense to me as I followed what is documented in github api as well. @Vampire can you put an example on how you did it?

Comment: As i said, i just took the command of OP, replaced the token and the username and it worked.

Comment: I found the solution, see my answer.

Comment: I re-generated the token (with the same privileges it had) and guess what ? it surprisingly started working for me!!! ...Thanks for taking of your time to review this. I really appreciate it!!!!.

Comment: I have hit the issue and no one answer is helped. Only add of `repo (Full control of private repositories)` permission has worked. Seems a private repository must have a different set of permissions.

Answer (score 5):

Your access token misses the privilege `public_repo`.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem and found that removing the slash in the path after releases solved it:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/codeStyler87/test-tags/releases
```

not

```
https://api.github.com/repos/codeStyler87/test-tags/releases/
```

Either that or it's completely random like the OP.